# Selecting array of array based on condition in array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this array :

```
a = [[255,255,255,0],[255,255,254,0],[1,2,3,4],[1,4,6,8],[1,5,7,0]]
```

I have tried using numpy but i don't know how to do it further.

I want it omit all the array of array having 0 in the `a[i][3]`, that is I want my output as  `a=[[1,2,3,4],[1,4,6,8]]`, removing all the array of array having zero in its last index. I am a beginner in python and i want to know the best way to carry out this,thanks.

I have tried using numpy but i don't know how to do it further.

```
a=[[255,255,255,0],[255,255,254,0],[1,2,3,4],[1,4,6,8],[1,5,7,0]]
print(a[:,a!=0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension :

```
a = [[255,255,255,0],[255,255,254,0],[1,2,3,4],[1,4,6,8],[1,5,7,0]]
a = [x for x in a if x[3] != 0]
```

---

Output :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much,that worked,where can i find resources for this

Comment: This is called list comprehensions, you can find different documentations about it, here is one for example [source](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).   If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a numpy solution.

```
a = np.array([[255,255,255,0],[255,255,254,0],[1,2,3,4],[1,4,6,8],[1,5,7,0]])
mask = a[:, 3] != 0 
print(a[mask])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [1 4 6 8]]
```